# Implementation of destructor as a function?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I have a question about a destructor's implementation for a class. I understand the right way is using the ~ operator, but take a look at the following code:

```
class foo
{
private:
int* abc;

public:
foo()
{
abc = new int(2);
}

~foo()
{
delete abc;
}

void func()
{
delete abc;
}
}
```

Now let us say that the main function is defined as below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
foo a;
a.func();
}
```

Upon the function call of func() in main, does this work in the exact same way as the destructor? What is the difference between the destructor and this function in any similar setting?

Comment: ~ isn't an operator in this case.

Comment: `a->func();` compile error `->` needs to be `.`

Comment: '~' as in the standard notation for implementing a destructor. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is very very bad code.. You will have a double delete at the end of main function

Comment: It's worth noting that your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: For the record, this isn't my code. This is an interview question. I was sort of confused by this.

Comment: Well, a good start on the answer would be explaining the undefined behaviour ;)

Comment: My response was that a destructor is ALWAYS a virtual function. So, the func() function won't be appropriate to use as a destructor. But the question still stands about whether this is the same as a destructor or not. If not, what is the difference?

Comment: @Chris: Why is it unexplained behavior?

Comment: because it will delete abc twice, once in func another in destructor

Comment: @Nathan822, Actually, a destructor isn't always virtual. In fact, it's not virtual unless you explicitly say so. Anyway, what you `delete` has to be valid memory allocated with `new`. Either copying your object or calling `func` kills that idea.

Comment: @chris: When I call func(), isn't the data being deleted valid data? My intuition is that a constructor was called to instantiate an object, and the func is being called on that object's member 'abc'.

Comment: @Nathan822, Sure it is, but then it isn't when the destructor does so as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`func()` and `~foo()` do the exact same thing. And that's the problem. When `a` goes out of scope, its destructor `~foo()` will automatically be called, resulting in `abc` being deleted *twice*. One way to get around it would be to set `abc` to `NULL` at the end of `func()` after the `delete`, so that when the destructor gets called it `delete`s a `NULL` pointer, which is a special case in C++ where nothing is actually done and is a valid operation.

Or, of course, the code could be rewritten in a way that actually made sense and accomplished something.

And just to be really clear, the "difference" between `func()` and `~foo()` is how/when they're called, not in what they do. `func()` is manually called by the user, while `~foo()` is automatically called when the variable goes out of scope. `func()` may be called zero or more times (it's up to the programmer), but the compiler will call `~foo()` exactly once (no more, no less) in this code.

Comment: @Nathan822 There is actually one important difference in functionality, in the general case. Whenever a destructor is called (explicitly or implicitly), it will also result in the destructors of all its bases and child elements being called (in reverse order of declaration).

Comment: @Nathan822 Please note though, that explicitly calling a destructor is a *bad idea* unless you've allocated the memory using *placement new*, because for locals it would cause the destructor to be called twice, and for dynamically allocated memory, it will not free the memory allocated for the object. Which means you either get double destructor calls or a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Few differences beyond the obvious differences in definition.

Destructor

- invoked automatically at the end of scope or at a `delete` call, can be invoked manually, rarely a good idea
- Calls destructors of member variables and base classes.

Run of the mill Method

- invoked manually

In this particular case, no base classes and only member field is the `int *` ptr which doesnt have a destructor, so in this case they are identical except for the method of invocation.